# Are there other alternatives to the Mauchly's sphericity test?

Tags: anova, sphericity

Are there other alternatives to the Mauchly's sphericity test?

I am about to run a Repeated Measures ANOVA and a One-Way ANOVA and must perform a pre-requisite check on the dataset. I was wondering what are the other alternatives to Mauchly's sphericity test.

Comment: It might help to elaborate a bit on what you're testing and why. Otherwise, the answer is trivially "yes": I myself am partial to the $\chi^2$ test today :-)

Comment: Hi, I have changed my answer slightly. Essentially what i am doing is creating a web application that performs several statistical functions (t test, anova(s) etc).But i need a test to check if it is okay to perform an anova and was wondering what are the other alternatives to Mauchly. Thanks for your input!